# php, mysql , xampp, database

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

It is showing connected but table not created. can you please tell where the error is?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "Students");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Connection Failed".mysqli_connect_errno();
} else{
  echo"connected";
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"Students");
$sql= "create table information(TITLE varchar(10), LNAME varchar(20),FNAME varchar(20),DESIGNATION varchar(20),DEPARTMENT varchar(20),ORGANISATION varchar(20),ADDRESS varchar(30),PRODUCT varchar(20),PERIOD varchar(20))";
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
  echo "Table Created";
} else {
  echo "Table not Created";
}
?>
```

Comment: Getting any errors?

Comment: you already mentioned the db name, then why using select_db() again?

Comment: DB connection already connected, you don't need this line `mysqli_select_db($con,"Students");`

Comment: `mysqli_select_db($con,"Students");` does this executes without errors?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code or query. Check what the error is after the query with `mysqli_error($con)`

Comment: @the.salman.a he is passing 4 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed a few errors (removed white space & added `{}` to the last else statement):
try the following :

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Students");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connection Failed" . mysqli_connect_errno();
} else {
    echo"connected";
}
mysqli_select_db($con, "Students");
$sql = "create table information(TITLE varchar(10), LNAME varchar(20),FNAME 
varchar(20),DESIGNATION varchar(20),DEPARTMENT varchar(20),ORGANISATION 
varchar(20),ADDRESS varchar(30),PRODUCT varchar(20),PERIOD varchar(20))";
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "Table Created";
} else {
    echo "Table not Created";
}
?>
```